# Error HTTP 405 when Session Starts using load balancing NGINX

Tags: apache, nginx, spring-security, proxy, load-balancing

I implement Load Balancer using NGINX , but when I try to use some of the webapps developed in Java using Spring Security, when I try to login in one of the apps returns HTTP 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported.

[image]

My NGINX conf file like this:

```
upstream myapp {
        server 172.16.80.49:8095;      
        server 172.16.53.31:8091;
    }

server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://172.16.80.49:8092;
        }
        location /docentes {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://myapp;
        }
        location /gerentes {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://myapp;
        }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

how i can solve this, I suppose the app the problem would be csrf token

[image]

Comment: It seems that the exception is thrown by Tomcat, not by NGINX. Which is the HTTP request sent? Is it GET or is it POST? If the request sent by your browser is POST, then the problem seems to be with your application code (Spring-MVC?) which does not support POST method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change my cof to:

```
upstream myapp {
        ip_hash;
        server 172.16.80.49:8095;      
        server 172.16.53.31:8091;
    }

server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://172.16.80.49:8092;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  Host  $http_host;
        }
        location /docentes {
            proxy_pass http://myapp;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
        location /gerentes {
            proxy_pass http://myapp;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;      
        }
        location /dashboard {
            proxy_pass http://myapp;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;      
        }



    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```